# Login Validation of an imageview in android

Tags: android

validation: Login Form :
I am able validate the email :if there is error, it should not go to next page.

But,There is one field. Imageview.  i picked  an image from the gallery and set it to imageview.  there is also no probem.

When there is no  image in Imageview,  it should rise the error because of no image which is like email validation.
How validate Imageview like login validation

it should not move to next page ...

..How is it possible. any help? thank's in advance.
I can validate successfully with below code like that Imageview which i want.

```
enter code here


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
  implements View.OnClickListener {

//The view objects
private EditText editTextName, editTextEmail, editTextMobile,
        editTextDob, editTextAge;

private Button buttonSubmit;

//defining AwesomeValidation object
private AwesomeValidation awesomeValidation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //initializing awesomevalidation object
    /*        awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.editTextName, "^[A-Za-z\\s]{1,}[\\.]{0,1}[A-Za-z\\s]{0,}$", R.string.nameerror);

    * The library provides 3 types of validation
    * BASIC
    * COLORATION
    * UNDERLABEL
    * */
    awesomeValidation = new AwesomeValidation(ValidationStyle.BASIC);

    //initializing view objects
    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMobile);
    editTextDob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDob);
    editTextAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAge);

    buttonSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);


    //adding validation to edittexts
    awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.editTextEmail, Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS, R.string.nameerror);
    awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.editTextMobile, "^[2-9]{2}[0-9]{8}$", R.string.nameerror);
    awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.editTextDob, "^(?:(?:31(\\/|-|\\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\\/|-|\\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?\\d{2})$|^(?:29(\\/|-|\\.)0?2\\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\\d|2[0-8])(\\/|-|\\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?\\d{2})$", R.string.nameerror);
    awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.editTextAge, Range.closed(13, 60), R.string.ageerror);

    buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void submitForm() {
    //first validate the form then move ahead
    //if this becomes true that means validation is successfull
    if (awesomeValidation.validate()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Validation Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //process the data further
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == buttonSubmit) {
        submitForm();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. You can check image is selected or not in onActivityResult()**

**2. so just override the onActivityResult()**

**3. In data, if you selected the image then it will have the path of image otherwise it will be null**

**Note: I have used Glide library for display image. (This part is optional )    So just add it in build.gradle(Module App)**

> compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

```
   Uri filePath;// class variable

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (data != null) {
            // set selected image in image view
            filePath = data.getData();
            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(filePath).into(imafeView);
        } else {
            // set default or any error image in image view
            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(R.drawable.err_image_name).into(imafeView);
            Log.e(TAG, "nothing Selected: ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks try say result

Comment: you can't set Error on imageview either set A Toast or set a Error image as a image resource.

Comment: Hello Jaya, Instead of showing error in image view, I would suggest you to show an error image into image view...  and please check my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Take one boolean flag and set it default false

```
boolean isImageAdded = false;
```

now from where you are choosing the image from Camera or Gallary , if your image data is not null in `onActivityResult` method make `isImageAdded = true`

and in last for validation just check `isImageAdded` is it true or false.

Comment: more with detail

Answer (score 1):

You can you following code:

Open Gallery:

```
private void openGallery() {
        Intent pOpenGalleryIntent = new Intent();
        pOpenGalleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        pOpenGalleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(pOpenGalleryIntent, getString(R.string.app_name)),1);
    }
```

OnActivityResult():

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Uri pSelectedImageUri = null;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                pSelectedImageUri = data.getData();
                //Set imageView

            }

    } else {
         //Validation fail
    }
}
```